# Python, take value of a list from an input

Tags: python

Hi guys i'm Learning python, i have this problem, for not create 1000 "if" function i would did that:

```
#Vari flag
print "choose flag"
print "(1) Syn"
print "(2) Ack"
print "(3) Push"
print "(4) Fin"
print "(5) Urg"
print "(6) Rst"

flag-list = ["--syn","--ack","--push","--fin","--urg","--rst"]
flag = raw_input(write number separated by comma: )
```

now i would take writed number and transform them in the text of "flag-list".

Comment: Do you mean `flag-list[int(flag) - 1]` ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `flag-list` is invalid, you are not allowed a hyphen in a variable name, try `flag_list`.  You have no quotes around the prompt in `raw_input()`.  `raw_input()` returns a string, to use it as an index value you need to convert the value to `int()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Note that variable names cannot contain hyphens
flag_list = ["--syn","--ack","--push","--fin","--urg","--rst"]

# This clearly has to be in quotes
user_input = raw_input("Enter numbers separated by comma:" )

# Split the user input string at the commas, and turn each element into an integer.
flag_nums = map(int, flag_num.split(','))

# List indexes start at 0, so subtract 1.
# Use brackets to access the Nth item in the list.
# This is a list comprehension.
flags = [flag_list[n - 1] for n in flag_nums]
```

Comment: I think you should use a for-in and split the flag_num, because at 
flag_num = it's write separeted by comma. @Jonathon Reinhart

Comment: Apparently you're better at deciphering the OP's very broken English than I am.